# What is the purpose of while and for loops, if statement in this code?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to understand the concept of Cookies in JavaScript. For that, I'm trying to understand the working of this code from http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username:

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

I've understood most of the things in this code, but still I have some doubts/queries (in **getCookie** function):

Doubt **1.** Purpose of **for** loop

Doubt **2.** Purpose of **if**

Doubt **3.** Purpose of **while** loop

Doubt **4.** Purpose of **return "";**

I'm asking about these because the script is running fine even without using these conditions. (I know the working of each inbuilt function in **getCookie** function. I just don't understand the use of above loops and conditions).

Here's what I want to say:

```
    function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    var c = ca[0];
    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
```

Even after I've changed the expiry date to a past date in `setCookie` function (`exdays*2000`), it is still displaying "Welcome to XYZ" message. That means Cookie is not deleted. But when I run the same code in a different browser, it is deleted. Why is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doubt 1. Purpose of for loop

All cookies are saved as a semicolon separated key-value (actually it is semicolon and space `;`). key and values are separated by equal-to (`=`) symbol. By iterating, you are checking all the keys and returning only the value of key which is matching the argument passed to the method

> Doubt 2. Purpose of if

To check if the current key from the iteration contains the cookie name that is passed to the method.

> Doubt 3. Purpose of while loop

To remove all spaces one by one. Actually this one can easily be improved by using `trim()` method.

```
//while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
c = c.trim();
```

> Doubt 4. Purpose of return "";

if there is no value found, then return an empty string rather than user having to check for the `null` or `undefined`.

> Even after I've changed the expiry date to a past date in setCookie
>   function (exdays*2000), it is still displaying "Welcome to XYZ"
>   message. That means Cookie is not deleted. But when I run the same
>   code in a different browser, it is deleted. Why is so?

It is possible (assuming this, since you have not shared any fiddle) that your setCookie method is not executed when you opened that page second time on the same browser.

Comment: Please answer the Query Sir

Comment: Please check this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username Try changing the expiry date to past. It still shows Welcome message. Please use same browser.

Comment: @VikasKumar This code is checking if the cookie exists or not. Only if it doesn't exists it is calling setCookie method, else it is returning the value of the cookie. So, this method is not called at first place.

Comment: So it might be possible that it is retrieving the earlier value of cookie that I saved using (exdays*24*60*60*1000)... And not setting the new cookie with expiry (exdays*2000) ? Am I right?

Comment: And one last question: Is "expiry="TIME" a cookie? Or is it written with a cookie just for expiry purpose?

Comment: @VikasKumar precisely that is what I meant.

Comment: @VikasKumar it is only for expiry purpose.

Answer (score 1):

### Doubt 1. Purpose of for loop

Cookies are stored as a single line string like this:

```
"Cookie_1=Cookie_value1;   Cookie_2=Cookie_value2; Cookie_3=Cookie_value3; Cookie_4=Cookie_value4;"
```

Then this is split into arrays with

```
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
```

So the value of ca is now ["Cookie_1=Cookie_value1","   Cookie_2=Cookie_value2"," Cookie_3=Cookie_value3"," Cookie_4=Cookie_value4",""]
which can be considered a cookie "entity" for each member of the array

### Doubt 3. Purpose of while loop

If you look at the values in the `ca` array, you will see that Cookie 2 has a value of `"   Cookie_2=Cookie_value2"`. There are leading spaces that we need to trim out so there goes the purpose of this while loop

```
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
```

### Doubt 2. Purpose of if

After the leading spaces are trimmed then you can check if the cookie name matches the one you are looking for.
For example, `"Cookie_3=Cookie_value3".indexOf("Cookie_3=")` is equal to 0

### Doubt 4. Purpose of return "";

This is just the default value to return if the cookie name specified is not found, something like a case default in switch case.

Comment: Thanks. That clears my first 3 doubts. I still don't understand Doubt 4. And please answer the query as well, that is written in the end of question.